# Different induction principles for Prop and Type

Tags: coq

I noticed that Coq synthesizes different induction principles on equality for Prop and Type. Does anybody have an explanation for that?

Equality is defined as

```
Inductive eq (A : Type) (x : A) : A -> Prop :=  eq_refl : x = x
```

And the associated induction principle has the following type:

```
eq_ind
 : forall (A : Type) (x : A) (P : A -> Prop),
   P x -> forall y : A, x = y -> P y
```

Now let's define a Type pendant of eq:

```
Inductive eqT {A:Type}(x:A):A->Type:= eqT_refl: eqT x x.
```

The automatically generated induction principle is

```
eqT_ind
 : forall (A : Type) (x : A) (P : forall a : A, eqT x a -> Prop),
   P x (eqT_refl x) -> forall (y : A) (e : eqT x y), P y e
```

Comment: Fun fact: if you do `Print eqT.`, then Coq prints back `Inductive eqT (A : Type) (x : A) : A -> Prop :=  eqT_refl : eqT x x`. It is `A -> Prop` not `A -> Type`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Note*: I'm going to use `_rect` principles everywhere instead of `_ind`, since `_ind` principles are usually implemented via the `_rect` ones.

## Type of `eqT_rect`

Let's take a look at the predicate `P`.
When dealing with inductive families, the number of arguments of `P` is equal to the number of *non-parametric* arguments (indices) + 1.

Let me give some examples (they can be easily skipped).

- Natural numbers don't have parameters at all:

  ```
  Inductive nat : Set :=  O : nat | S : nat -> nat.
  ```

  So, the predicate `P` will be of type `nat -> Type`.
- Lists have one parametric argument (`A`):

  ```
  Inductive list (A : Type) : Type :=
    nil : list A | cons : A -> list A -> list A.
  ```

  Again, `P` has only one argument: `P : list A -> Type`.
- Vectors are a different:

  ```
  Inductive vec (A : Type) : nat -> Type :=
    nil : vec A 0
  | cons : A -> forall n : nat, vec A n -> vec A (S n).
  ```

  `P` has 2 arguments, because `n` in `vec A n` is a non-parameteric argument:

  ```
  P : forall n : nat, vec A n -> Type
  ```

The above explains `eqT_rect` (and, of course, `eqT_ind` as a consequence), since the argument after `(x : A)` is non-parametric, `P` has 2 arguments:

```
P : forall a : A, eqT x a -> Type
```

which justifies the overall type for `eqT_rect`:

```
eqT_rect
     : forall (A : Type) (x : A) (P : forall a : A, eqT x a -> Type),
       P x (eqT_refl x) -> forall (y : A) (e : eqT x y), P y e
```

The induction principle obtained in this way is called a *maximal induction principle*.

## Type of `eq_rect`

The generated induction principles for inductive predicates (such as `eq`) are simplified to express proof irrelevance (the term for this is *simplified induction principle*).

When defining a predicate `P`, Coq simply drops the last argument of the predicate (which is the type being defined, and it lives in `Prop`). That's why the predicate used in `eq_rect` is unary. This fact shapes the type of `eq_rect`:

```
eq_rect : 
  forall (A : Type) (x : A) (P : A -> Type),
         P x -> forall y : A, x = y -> P y
```

## How to generate maximal induction principle

We can also make Coq generate non-simplified induction principle for `eq`:

```
Scheme eq_rect_max := Induction for eq Sort Type.
```

The resulting type is

```
eq_rect_max :
  forall (A : Type) (x : A) (P : forall a : A, x = a -> Type),
         P x eq_refl -> forall (y : A) (e : x = y), P y e
```

and it has the same structure as `eqT_rect`.

## References

For more detailed explanation see sect. 14.1.3 ... 14.1.6 of the book "Interactive Theorem Proving and Program Development (Coq'Art: The Calculus of Inductive Constructions)" by Bertot and Castéran (2004).

Comment: Remark to references: it's chapter 15 on the most recent French version.

Comment: I didn't know the authors put the whole [book](http://www.labri.fr/perso/casteran/CoqArt/coqartF.pdf) on the Internet for free! Moreover they seem to update it! And it seems to me I understand like 1/3 - 1/2 of the text with almost zero French knowledge :)

Comment: Note: although proof irrelevance is generally (implicitly) assumed and explains this simplified induction principle, Coq's logic does not imply it.

Comment: Correct! Proof Irrelevance as an axiom is stated [here](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.ProofIrrelevance.html). Many thanks to all the commenters!

Comment: I'll add that you can also ask Coq to generate the simplified version with `Scheme my_eqT_ind := Minimality for eqT Sort Prop`. See https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual015.html#sec570.

Comment: Updated link: https://coq.inria.fr/refman/user-extensions/proof-schemes.html#generation-of-induction-principles-with-scheme.