# Why is it impossible to perform induction on a term that is used in conclusion?

Tags: coq

Suppose the following particular scenario.

We have a definition of equality:

```
Inductive eqwal {A : Type} (x : A) : A -> Prop :=
    eqw_refl : eqwal x x.
```

And peano nats:

```
Inductive nawt : Prop :=
    | zewro : nawt
    | sawc  : nawt -> nawt.
```

We define addition on nats:

```
Fixpoint plaws (m n : nawt) : nawt :=
    match m with
      | zewro => n
      | sawc m' => sawc (plaws m' n)
    end.
```

And now we want to prove that zero is neutral from right wrt. summing:

```
Theorem neutral_r : forall n : nawt, eqwal (plaws n zewro) n.
```

Sadly the last line of the following proofscripts says "*Error: n is used in conclusion.*".

```
Proof.
intros.
induction n. - this is the culprit
```

There is not much about the error in official documentation and I am somewhat confused - why does this error occur?

Using the standard library, I can prove the theorem easily:

```
Theorem neutral_r : forall n : nat,
  n + 0 = n.
Proof.
  induction n; try reflexivity.
  cbn; rewrite IHn; reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you defined `nawt` with sort `Prop` instead of `Type` or `Set`. By default, the induction principles generated for propositions do not allow us to prove anything about proofs of those propositions. Consider the default induction principle generated for `nawt`:

```
Check nawt_ind.
> nawt_ind : forall P : Prop, P -> (nawt -> P -> P) -> nawt -> P
```

Because `nawt_ind` quantifies over `Prop`, and not over `nat -> Prop`, we cannot use it to prove your goal.

The solution is to set a few options that change Coq's default behavior, as in the following script.

```
Inductive eqwal {A : Type} (x : A) : A -> Prop :=
    eqw_refl : eqwal x x.

Unset Elimination Schemes.

Inductive nawt : Prop :=
    | zewro : nawt
    | sawc  : nawt -> nawt.

Scheme nawt_ind := Induction for nawt Sort Prop.

Set Elimination Schemes.

Fixpoint plaws (m n : nawt) : nawt :=
    match m with
      | zewro => n
      | sawc m' => sawc (plaws m' n)
    end.

Theorem eqwal_sym {A : Type} (x y : A) : eqwal x y -> eqwal y x.
Proof. intros H. destruct H. constructor. Qed.

Theorem neutral_r : forall n : nawt, eqwal (plaws n zewro) n.
Proof.
intros. induction n as [|n IH]; simpl.
- constructor.
- apply eqwal_sym in IH. destruct IH. constructor.
Qed.
```

The `Elimination Schemes` option causes Coq to automatically generate induction principles for data types and propositions. In this script, I merely turned it off, and used the `Scheme` command to generate the correct induction principle for `nawt`. For the `induction` tactic to work, it is important to give this principle the name `nawt_ind`: this is the default name that is generated by Coq, and is the one that `induction` looks for when called.

That being said, I would generally advise against defining a type of natural numbers in `Prop` instead of `Type`, because Coq imposes restrictions on how you can use things that live in `Prop`.  For instance, it is impossible to show that `zewro` is different from `sawc zewro`.

Comment: "I would generally advise against defining a type of natural numbers in Prop" Indeed! In fact, pedantically speaking it is not possible to define the a type of "natural numbers" in Prop. You won't be able to satisfy they meet the Peano Axioms, thus they can hardly be called "natural numbers".

Comment: Thank you! I've always thought I could blissfuly ignore the differences between Type and Prop and so far, it has, for the most part, worked. But after some careful reading, it seems they're fundamentally different and implications stretch far beyond efficiency of computation and proof erasure. I appreciate your answer.