# How to implement remove with a membership proof as an argument in Coq?

Tags: coq

```
data _∈_ {X : Set} (x : X) : (xs : List X) → Set where
  here! : {xs : List X} → x ∈ x ∷ xs
  there : {xs : List X} {y : X} (pr : x ∈ xs) → x ∈ y ∷ xs

remove : {X : Set} {x : X} (xs : List X) (pr : x ∈ xs) → List X
remove (_ ∷ xs) here!      = xs
remove (y ∷ xs) (there pr) = y ∷ remove xs pr
```

I am trying to translate the above definition from Agda to Coq and am running into difficulties.

```
Inductive Any {A : Type} (P : A -> Type) : list A -> Prop :=
  | here : forall {x : A} {xs : list A}, P x -> Any P (x :: xs)
  | there : forall {x : A} {xs : list A}, Any P xs -> Any P (x :: xs).

Definition In' {A : Type} (x : A) xs := Any (fun x' => x = x') xs.

Fixpoint remove {A : Type} {x : A} {l : list A} (pr : In' x l) : list A :=
  match l, pr with
  | [], _ => []
  | _ :: ls, here _ _ => ls
  | x :: ls, there _ pr => x :: remove pr
  end.
```

```
Incorrect elimination of "pr0" in the inductive type "@Any":
the return type has sort "Type" while it should be "Prop".
Elimination of an inductive object of sort Prop
is not allowed on a predicate in sort Type
because proofs can be eliminated only to build proofs.
```

In addition to this error, if I leave the `[]` case out Coq is asks me to provide it despite it being absurd.

Up to this point, I've thought that Agda and Coq were the same languages with a different front end, but now I am starting to think they are different under the hood. Is there a way to replicate the remove function in Coq and if not, what alternative would you recommend?

**Edit**: I also want to keep the proof between `In` and `In'`. Originally I made `In'` a `Type` rather than a `Prop`, but that made the following proof fail with a type error.

```
Fixpoint In {A : Type} (x : A) (l : list A) : Prop :=
  match l with
  | [] ⇒ False
  | x' :: l' ⇒ x' = x ∨ In x l'
  end.

Theorem In_iff_In' : 
  forall {A : Type} (x : A) (l : list A), 
  In x l <-> In' x l.
Proof. 
intros.
split.
- intros.
  induction l.
  + inversion H.
  + simpl in H.
    destruct H; subst.
    * apply here. reflexivity.
    * apply there. apply IHl. assumption.
- intros.
  induction H.
  + left. subst. reflexivity.
  + right. assumption.
Qed.
```

```
In environment
A : Type
x : A
l : list A
The term "In' x l" has type "Type" while it is expected to have type 
"Prop" (universe inconsistency).
```

The `In` here is from the [Logic chapter](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Logic.html#lab187) of SF. I have a solution of the pigeonhole principle in Agda, so I want this bijection in order to convert to the form that the exercise asks.

**Edit2**:

```
Theorem remove_lemma :
  forall {A} {x} {y} {l : list A} (pr : In' x l) (pr' : In' y l),
  x = y \/ In' y (remove pr).
```

I also outright run into universe inconsistency in this definition even when using `Type` when defining `In'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an informative proof of membership. Right now, your `Any` takes values in `Prop`, which, due to its limitations on elimination (see the error message you got), is consistent with the axiom `forall (P: Prop) (x y: P), x = y`. This means that if you have some term that depends on a term whose type is in `Prop` (as is the case with `remove`), it has to only use the fact that such a term exists, not what term it is specifically. Generally, you can't use elimination (usually pattern matching) on a `Prop` to produce anything other than something that's also a `Prop`.

There are three essentially different proofs of `In' 1 [1; 2; 1; 3; 1; 4]`, and, depending which proof is used, `remove p` might be `[2; 1; 4; 1; 4]`, `[1; 2; 3; 1; 4]` or `[1; 2; 1; 3; 4]`. So the output depends on the specific proof in an essential way.

To fix this, you can simply replace the `Prop` in `Inductive Any {A : Type} (P : A -> Type) : list A -> Prop` with `Type`.<sup>1</sup> Now we can eliminate into non-`Prop` types and your definition of `remove` works as written.

---

To answer your edits, I think the biggest issue is that some of your theorems/definitions need `In'` to be a `Prop` (because they depend on uninformative proofs) and others need the informative proof.

I think your best bet is to keep `In'` as a `Type`, but then prove uninformative versions of the theorems. In the standard libary, in `Coq.Init.Logic`, there is an inductive type `inhabited`.

```
Inductive inhabited (A: Type): Prop :=
| inhabits: A -> inhabited A.
```

This takes a type and essentially forgets anything specific about its terms, only remembering if it's inhabited or not. I think your theorem and lemma are provable if you simply replace `In' x l` with `inhabited (In' x l)`. I was able to prove a variant of your theorem whose conclusion is simply `In x l <-> inhabited (In' x l)`. Your proof mostly worked, but I had to use the following simple lemma in one step:

```
Lemma inhabited_there {A: Type} {P: A -> Type} {x: A} {xs: list A}:
  inhabited (Any P xs) -> inhabited (Any P (x :: xs)).
```

Note: even though `inhabited A` is basically just a `Prop` version of `A` and we have `A -> inhabited A`, we can't prove `inhabited A -> A` in general because that would involve choosing an arbitrary element of `A`.<sup>2</sup>

---

1. I also suggested `Set` here before, but this doesn't work since the inductive type depends on `A`, which is in `Type`.
2. In fact, I believe that the proof assistant Lean uses something very similar to this for its axiom of choice.

Comment: `Set` outright fails for me, but I run into universe inconsistency when using `Type`. Please see my edit. Is there a good reference on what the difference between `Type`, `Set` and `Prop` is?

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322534/coq-prop-versus-set-in-typen) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568683/why-is-it-impossible-to-perform-induction-on-a-term-that-is-used-in-conclusion) seem relevant. I think your problems with the lemmas are just with the notations `<->` and `\/`. They unfold to terms that only take `Prop`s, so you'll need to use the `Type` equivalent.

Comment: I thought that `<->` might be an issue, but even when using `->` I run into a problem where `destruct` fails to work on `H : x0 = x \/ In x l` because it is a `Type` rather than a `Prop` all of a sudden. I am having no luck with this.

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic Yeah, there's some other problems, but I think I've found a satisfactory solution. I'm editing it in now.